# Meaning of "exploiting the fact that" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have copied this sentence from [OXITEC](http://www.oxitec.com/health/our-products/aedes-agypti-ox513a/)

> Before release, male and female pupae are separated mechanically, exploiting the fact that they are naturally significantly different in size.

Does this means that "Using the fact that they are different in size, they can be separated without any thinking."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, *taking advantage* of the fact that... ; the fact they are naturally different in size somehow facilitate the separation.